# XML - Multiple Nodes With Same Name on Same Level

Tags: xml, vb.net

Considering I have the following XML file:

```
<family> 
  <name gender="Male">
    <firstname>Tom</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <phone>111111</phone>
    <phone>222222</phone>
  </name>
  <name gender="Female">
    <firstname>Dale</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <phone>111111</phone>
    <phone>222222</phone>
  </name>
</family>
```

I'm using an XmlTextReader to parse the XML, my code goes like this:

```
Dim m_xmlr As XmlTextReader
m_xmlr = New XmlTextReader(InputXML)
m_xmlr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
m_xmlr.Read()
m_xmlr.Read()
While Not m_xmlr.EOF
    m_xmlr.Read()
    If Not m_xmlr.IsStartElement() Then
        Exit While
    End If
    Dim gender as string = m_xmlr.GetAttribute("gender")
    m_xmlr.Read()
    Dim FirstName As Array = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("firstname")
    Dim LastName As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("lastname")
    Dim phone As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("phone")
End While
m_xmlr.Close()
```

My question is, how can i get both phone nodes to put in 2 different variables?

PS: I can't modify the xml, and no att can be added to any node.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another `ReadElementString` after the first:

```
Dim phone1 As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("phone")
Dim phone2 As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("phone")
```

Note: to get your sample to work I had to make some small modifications, i.e.

```
While Not m_xmlr.EOF
    Dim gender As String = m_xmlr.GetAttribute("gender")            
    m_xmlr.Read()            
    Dim FirstName As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("firstname")
    Dim LastName As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("lastname")
    Dim phone1 As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("phone")
    Dim phone2 As String = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("phone")        
End While
```